# Some idea to do this blocks diagram?

Tags: diagrams, block

Some idea to draw this blocks diagram:

[image]

I only have this:

```
    \documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[block1/.style={draw, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1.8cm},
    block2/.style={draw, minimum width=1cm, minimum height=.8cm},
    >=Stealth]
    \node[block1] (b1) {1};
    \node[block1, right=5cm of b1] (b2) {2};
    \draw[->] (b1.east)--node[above] {c} (b2.west);
    \draw[->] (b2.east)--++(0:1cm) node[right] {exit};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Thanks!!!

Comment: $\mathrm{x[n]}$ is an easy part. ;-)

Comment: On this site, a question should typically revolve around an abstract issue (e.g. "How do I get a double horizontal line in a table?") rather than a concrete application (e.g. "How do I make this table?"). Questions that look like "Please do this complicated thing for me" tend to get closed because they are either "off topic", "too broad", or "unclear". Please try to make your question clear and simple by giving a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228): you'll stand a greater chance of getting help.

Comment: yess. Its good idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
    \documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,calc,positioning}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
    block/.style={draw, minimum width=22mm, minimum height=8mm},
   sum/.style={circle, draw, minimum size=6mm, inner sep=0pt,
               node contents={\huge$+$}},
  mult/.style={circle, draw, minimum size=6mm, inner sep=0pt,
               node contents={\huge$\times$}},
            >=Stealth,
node distance=12mm and 6mm]
\node (b1) [block]              {$h_1[n]$};
\node (b2) [block,below=of b1]  {$h_2[n]$};
    \coordinate[left=of $(b1.west)!0.5!(b2.west)$] (in);
    \coordinate[left=of $(b1.east)!0.5!(b2.east)$] (out);
\node (m)  [mult, right=of b2];
\node (s)  [sum,right=of out -| m.west];
\node (b3) [block,right=of s]   {$h_3[n]$};
%
\draw[<- ] (in) -- node[above] {$x[n]$} + (-12mm,0);
\draw[<->] (b2.west) -| (in) |- (b1.west);
\draw[->]   (b1) -| (s);
\draw[->]   (b2) -- (m);
\draw[->]   (m)  -| (s);
\draw[->]   (s)  -- (b3);
\draw[->]   (b3.east)  -- node[above] {$y[n]$} + (12mm,0);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: WOOOOW its perfect, thank you very much. Have a nice day